# Why list doesn't appear on the page? What are the errors in my React-Redux (Api) application? And how to fix them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

First, I made a small application on the React.js. Using the `fetch` method, I take the API

And these are the main files of my application:

Index.js:(action)

```
export const SHOW_AIRPLANES = "SHOW_AIRPLANES";

export function showAirplanes() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    fetch("https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/25-08-2019").then(response => {
      dispatch({ type: SHOW_AIRPLANES, payload: response.data });
    });
  };
}
```

airplanes.js:(reducer)

```
import { SHOW_AIRPLANES } from '../actions'

const initialState = {
    list: []
}

export function showAirplanes(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case SHOW_AIRPLANES:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {list: action.payload})
        default:
            return state 
    }

}
```

index.js(reducer):

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { showAirplanes } from "./airplanes";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: showAirplanes
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use the `createStore` function like so:

```
const initialData = {}; // whatever you want as initial data
const store = createStore(reducers, initialData, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Then pass it to your provider

```
<Provider store={store}>
 {...}
</Provider
```

next, when you map your reducers inside the `combineReducers` function, each key in this object represents a piece of your state. So when you do `user: showAirplanes` it means that you intend to use it in the `mapStateToProps` with `state.user.list` so I think you meant to call it `airplane: showAirplanes`.

Then, your reducer name is not informative enough, I would suggest to change it to `airplanesReducer`.

Next issue, the call to fetch returns a response that has JSON that must be resolved.

Change this:

```
fetch("https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/25-08-2019").then(response => {
      dispatch({ type: SHOW_AIRPLANES, payload: response.data });
    });
```

To this:

```
fetch("https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/25-08-2019")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({ type: SHOW_AIRPLANES, payload: response.body.departure });
    });
```

Note that I've changed the value that you need to resolve from the response as well.

Inside your `App.js` component you need to create a constructor and bind the `renderAirplaneList` function to `this`

```
// Inside the App class
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.renderAirplaneList = this.renderAirplaneList.bind(this);
}
```

And finally (I hope I didn't miss anything else), you map your state in the `App.js` component to `{ airplanes: state.airplanes.list}` so the name of the prop you expect inside your component is `props.airplanes`.

```
renderAirplaneList() {
    if (!this.props.airplanes.length) {
        return null;
    }

    const arr = this.props.airplanes || [];

    return arr.map(airplane => {
      return (
        <tr key={airplane.id}>
          <td>{airplane.ID}</td>
          <td>{airplane.term}</td>
          <td>{airplane.actual}</td>
          <td>{airplane["airportToID.city_en"]}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
```

Make sure you go over the documentation of React and Redux, they have all the information you need.

Good luck.

Comment: thank you very much! I also wish you good luck!
also wanted to ask you why we are writing here:
```const store = createStore(reducers, initialData, applyMiddleware(thunk));```
word ```reducers``` and not: ```rootReducer ```?

Comment: @vrm111 This is your default export `rootReducer`, once you import the default to another module you can give it any name you'd like. you did this: `import reducers from './reducers';` so the name you selected is `reducers`.

Answer (score 0):

aren't you suppose to send some parameters to this call?

`this.props.showAirplanes()`

it seems that it has 2 parameters: state and action, although state seems to have already it's default value